# Multiple addressed One-Wire communication for RPI

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Raspberry PI or any other product.

I am looking for a solution like; Maybe 32 ports bus for a linux device.

Port 1 - Onewire1
Port 2 - Onewire2
.
.
.
Port 32 - Onewire32

Main objective is that i want to know get the one-wire id at specific port.
What id is connected on Port 20 for example.

Thanks in advance.